# Android ADB Shell ~ How to List a Process' Threads?

Tags: android, multithreading, process

I'm trying to monitor the list of threads a process has.  I'm hoping it can be viewed via ADB Shell.  I am aware of listing the process:

adb shell ps -p

But how do i go an extra layer deeper for that process' threads?

Using: Android 4.4.2

Comment: If it's only for debugging purposes, you might be better off just opening up the debugger view / attach the debugger to your running application in Android Studio and drill through the threads there, no?

Comment: Thomas, this will suffice.  Thanks.

Comment: also, at least in my testing in the emulator and galaxy devices, adb shell lsof -p <pid> and adb shell ps -T as suggested all over the planet do not work for me either. Both of those commands never show me my threads, just the outer process, despite knowing that I have threads running. I second @ThomasKeller, use a debug session where possible

Answer (score 4):

You can find the option you need using `adb shell ps --help`. One way is to use `adb shell ps -T | grep <PID>`, where `<PID>` is the thread ID. You can find it using `adb shell ps -A`

Example on Windows 10:

```
PS C:\Users\languoguang> adb shell ps -A | findstr "system_server"
system        3107  1218 14800384 722996 do_epoll_wait      0 S system_server
PS C:\Users\languoguang> adb shell ps -T | findstr "3107" | findstr "Input"
system        3107  3332  1218 14800384 723868 do_epoll_wait      0 S InputDispatcher
system        3107  3333  1218 14800384 723868 do_epoll_wait      0 S InputReader
PS C:\Users\languoguang>
```

Comment: `bad pid '-T'`, on older android -t is for thread.

Answer (score 1):

The command you are looking for is `ps -t`. That would do the trick.

Comment: No, `adb shell ps -t` shows processes attached to a TTY. `adb shell ps -T` shows threads. (Note the capital letter.)

Comment: Older Android with minimal `ps` implementation uses `-t` for threads.